# В Swift версии 3.0 не получается создать pickerview, выдает ошибку при попытке присваивания picker1.delegate = self

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPrinterPickerControllerDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var picker1: UIPickerView!

    var days = ["Everydays", "Saturday", "Sunday"]





    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        picker1.delegate = self
        picker1.dataSource = self
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return days.count

    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return days[row]

    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        label1.text = days[row]
    }


}
```

Comment: А какая ошибка то?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вероятнее всего ваша ошибка тут `UIPrinterPickerControllerDelegate`, Вы не тот протокол указали - нужен `UIPickerViewDelegate`.